# Constant Velocity Jitters in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-physics, skphysicsbody

I'm applying a constant velocity to one of my nodes like this in the update function:

```
// Set a constant velocity to the right:
node.physicsBody?.velocity.dx = 300
```

When I print the velocity in the didSimulatePhysics function, it prints out around 290. Ok, I'm losing some velocity to linearDamping, makes sense. But it doesn't stay constant.

Every 10-15 seconds there will be an unexplained jitter in the velocity (from the didSimulatePhysics print). For 6 or 7 frames, the velocity will fluctuate from 285-295. Slower, then faster. So I'll get a 287, then a 294, then a 286, then a 294. Never two slow or two fast in a row.

This is my main character, tracked by my camera, and the small change in velocity makes the camera appear to jitter whenever this happens.

I'm far away from any collisions, but note that I am ignoring collisions on this node and have restitution set to 0:

```
node.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
node.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
```

Is the physics simulation lagging and then trying to make up for it on the next frame (FPS is pegged at 60)? Or possibly running into rounding issues?

Is there a way to get an exactly constant velocity in one direction on every frame?

Adding an example of the actual change in node.position.x per frame when moving straight through the air with no collision, setting a velocity.dx of 300 every update:

```
3.82861328125 // this is the norm - thousands of these before this blip)
3.82861328125
3.82861328125
5.740478515625 // blip begins
1.9150390625
3.82861328125
5.740478515625
1.9150390625
5.740478515625
1.9150390625
5.740478515625
1.9150390625
5.740478515625
3.82861328125 // blip ends
3.82861328125
3.82861328125
```

Comment: Regarding the camera jittering, most games will smooth the camera so that the camera will move to the position overtime instead of instantaneously so that scenarios like the one you described appear fluid. Now regarding your actual problem, if you are setting the velocity in the update method (that is, continuously) the velocity should stay constant. However sprite kit implements a variable time step, so jittering might appear in the position when the frame rate drops. Are you running on the simulator or device. And are you positive there are no external forces like gravity, friction?

Comment: Good thoughts - I am in fact lerping to the new position, but the change is still (barely) perceivable because the camera is otherwise so steady. This is on an iPhone 6 device. The FPS meter stays pegged at 60 with CPU around 5%, but it certainly seems like a tiny bit of lag. Definitely no friction. Gravity is on (gravity is why I'm using a physics node) but would it affect horizontal velocity? And only once every 10-15 seconds, but only a few frames. Perhaps ARC is cleaning something up and causing a very small amount of frame rate lag? Instruments shows no CPU spikes. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Very strange. If you want to debug this issue a little further, you could start by seeing if it's indeed the frame rate by keeping track of your own delta time that sprite kit gives you in the update function. This is because you can't always go by what the SKView FPS shows you because it's simply an average. If you calculate your own delta time you can see what's happening during the jittery moment. If the delta time shows 1/60 constantly then you know the jittery movement must be caused by something else. It may also be helpful to reproduce this issue in a sample project.

Comment: You may also want to try running your project on release mode so that a lot of the debugging overhead is removed. And lastly (and this may sound odd) you may want to try deleting the app and cleaning your build folder. Very rarely during my sprite kit game a build would be very lagy and doing this always fixed the issue. Again this might be a totally separate issue than the one you are facing, I'm just trying to give you as much info as possible.

Comment: Interesting (5.740478515625 + 1.9150390625)/2 = 3.8277... It does look like it is over shooting then correcting the next frame. I would suspect that if you logged the time per frame you would see a spike there too. 60fps is an average and because it is only a few frames in the grand scheme of things you likely won't see a dip in fps or rather it won't report it. As to why this is happening every 10 to 15 mins I am unsure. I would assume 10 -15 is an estimate. I would actually clock it to see if there are any constancies with the time it takes to skip.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with SpriteKit physics is that it is using a variable time step which does not work well especially with constant movement. This mean that SpriteKit updates your physics in each frame with deltaTime that passed from the last frame. This time is never exactly the same even if you maintain constant 60 FPS. To solve this problem it might be a good idea to use a constant time step for physics simulation. Unfortunately in SpriteKit there is no way to control the time step for physics simulation and it is always tied to the frame rate. If you would use an engine which allows to update physics manually you could implement constant time step for physics simulation for example in the following way:

```
-(void)update:(double)dt
{
  double fixedDt = 1.0/60.0; // or you can put for example 1.0/300.0 to have more physics updates per frame

  self.difference += MIN(dt, 0.1); // prevent too big dt changes

  while (self.difference > fixedDt)
  {
      [self updatePhysics:fixedDt];
      self.difference -= fixedDt;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately in SpriteKit you can't control this and this is the reason why you will always see some small jitters even at 60 FPS in constant movement. You have few solutions:

- ignore this and just live with it
- try using different physics engine for example Chipmunk or Box2D
- do not use any physics engine at all

You can also find more information about variable/constant time step for physics here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/when-should-i-use-a-fixed-or-variable-time-step